# Инициализация одного сладера в нескольких блоках

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Здравствуйте! Ситуация следующая: имеется страница с множеством блоков, в каждом из которых присутствует слайдер. Делать под каждый блок отдельный слайдер - не вариант (блоков очень много), поэтому думал как поступить.. пока случайным образом не обнаружил, что выдумывать велосипед нет необходимости.

Используя [swiper](http://idangero.us/swiper/#.V-4ECvmLSUk) достаточно инициализации одного слайдера на странице, все работает корректно, что было проверено в [codepen](http://codepen.io/Vlastelin/pen/GjEEKE) (смотрите лучше на кодпен, здесь все поехало).

```js
var mySwiper = new Swiper ('.swiper-container', {
    nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',
  })
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #d3d3d3;
}
.item {
  height: 250px;
  width: 30%;
  background: #fff;
 
}
.swiper-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.swiper-slide {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/3.3.1/css/swiper.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/3.3.1/css/swiper.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/3.3.1/js/swiper.js"></script>



<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="item">
      <div class="swiper-container">
          <div class="swiper-wrapper">
              <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
              <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
              <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
          </div>

          <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
          <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="swiper-container">
          <div class="swiper-wrapper">
              <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
              <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
              <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
          </div>

          <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
          <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
      <div class="item">
      <div class="swiper-container">
          <div class="swiper-wrapper">
              <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
              <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
              <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
          </div>

          <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
          <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
      <div class="item">
      <div class="swiper-container">
          <div class="swiper-wrapper">
              <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
              <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
              <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
          </div>

          <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
          <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
      <div class="item">
      <div class="swiper-container">
          <div class="swiper-wrapper">
              <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
              <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
              <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
          </div>

          <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
          <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
      <div class="item">
      <div class="swiper-container">
          <div class="swiper-wrapper">
              <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
              <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
              <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
          </div>

          <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
          <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
      <div class="item">
      <div class="swiper-container">
          <div class="swiper-wrapper">
              <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
              <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
              <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
          </div>

          <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
          <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
      <div class="item">
      <div class="swiper-container">
          <div class="swiper-wrapper">
              <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
              <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
              <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
          </div>

          <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
          <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
      <div class="item">
      <div class="swiper-container">
          <div class="swiper-wrapper">
              <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
              <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
              <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
          </div>

          <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
          <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  
</div>
```

Но на практике ситуация, к сожалению, иная: при использовании одного слайдера в нескольких блоках он перестает работать от слова совсем. Ума не приложу почему. Может кто-то ответить на этот вопрос? [Ссылка на страницу](http://cyprus.890m.com/Cyprus/sale.html) где слайдер не работает.

Comment: Первое что могу сказать - на странице у вас ошибка от swiper висит. Просмотрите её внимательно

Comment: В том то и дело - несколько раз проверял правильность подключения, инициализации, структуры свайпера - все верно. Откуда эти ошибки не могу понять.

Comment: Как тут написали - нужно искать конфликты. Раз это дело работает в "чистом виде" на коде пене - значит в вашем приложении что-то где то или 1) слишком глобально и мешает свайперу 2) сам свайпер что-то накрывает

Comment: Делать под каждый блок отдельный слайдер - не вариант.  
     
Конечно не вариант, достаточно сконструировать один конструктор объекта слайдера и вызывать его на необходимых блоках

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Посмотрите в консоль, у вас там ошибка

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeType' of null (swiper.min.js:15)

Тут два варианта:

- вы что то делаете не так
- библиотека с чем то конфликтует

Если не можете найти ошибку в коде, то установите не минифицироанный вариант библиотеки и разберитесь от куда ошибка появляется.

Comment: Удивительно. Заменил сжатый вариант библиотеки на полный и все заработало. Спасибо за совет.